# File has a different computed hash than specified in manifest

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0

I usually just create web apps in C# but have tried to turn my hand to creating a WinForms app. I have created an OpenVPN client which is basically a facade over the top of the `OpenVPN.exe`. The project requires the `OpenVPN.exe` file to be included and it is located like this:

```
 string ovpnLocation = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
      + "\\OpenVPN_Client\\openvpn.exe";
```

I have the following properties applied to the file in VS:

- **Build Action:** Content
- **Copy to Output Directory:** Copy Always

Now when I try to deploy the application with the ClickOnce Installer, I get the following error:

`File, openvpn.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.`

After cleaning, rebuilding, and following instructions in every other post I could find on the whole internet, I can't seem to get around this problem with these current settings. The only way I've been able to get it to install and run is to change the settings on the file to the following:

- **Build Action:** None
- **Copy to Output Directory:** Copy Always

Now with these settings, when deploying, I don't get the same hash error, but it seems the location of the file has moved and my code throws execptions all over the place because it not can't find it.

So there are 2 solutions to this:

- Resolve the hash problem and change no code.
- Find some now code to help me locate the file on the end-users machine.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by upgrading the project to .Net 4.0.

The problem with the file path was resolved by using a relative path:

```
 string ovpnLocation = "OpenVPN_Client\\openvpn.exe";
```

Instead of trying to create an absolute:

```
string ovpnLocation = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
  + "\\OpenVPN_Client\\openvpn.exe";
```